# Archiving messages on Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

Is there a specific place to create archive folders for my messages on Office 365?

I typically create subfolders under my inbox to store/archive my messages. Is this good enough for my messages to be archived or do I need to move them to a different location?

All folders are created on the server. I want all my messages to be on the server so that when I access my inbox through different clients -- including the browser, I want them to be available.

Comment: When you create subfolders in your inbox, are you creating them within an Archive.pst file or within on the server itself?  If you have a limited amount of space within your inbox (on the server) then `.PST `files have to be used.  Please edit your question to include enough information so your question can be answered.

Comment: Just updated the original post.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  If you are keeping all emails on the server, then the only thing you can do is to create folders to sort your email.  You are not really "archiving" the emails at that point though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the comments above, archive feature for Outlook client is to move emails from server to local PST files: [Archive items manually](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/archive-items-manually-ecf54f37-14d7-4ee3-a830-46a5c33274f6)

If you want to keep all items on the server, you may use Online Archive feature for Office 365.

Please refer to the details in the thread below which discussed in TechNet forum:

[Best Practice : How to Use online Archive](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dac025f5-e151-4c13-9f5a-b6c4cab52990/best-practice-how-to-use-online-archive?forum=onlineservicesexchange)